# Get number from N

Tags: php, php5, integer

I'm trying to find the shortest and best way to achieve the following:

Given input integer $N, get the following output:

- n = 0, output = 0
- n = 1, output = 0
- n = 2, output = 10
- n = 3, output = 100
- n = 4, output = 1000
- n = 5, output = 10000

I do this with the following code, but there must be a better option to do this.

```
<?php

    $n = 1;

    function getNumber($n) {
        if ($n === 0 OR $n === 1) {
            return "0";
        } else {
            return "1".str_repeat("0", $n -1);
        }
    }

    echo getNumber($n);
?>
```

Comment: Just an overall comment, but calling a function 'getNumber' when it returns a string may not be the best solution to your problem

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765). I've rolled back Rev 2 → 1.

Comment: Allright, won't do it again! Tnx :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you want something short like is

```
echo ($n <= 1) ? 0 : pow(10, $n - 1);
```

Answer (score 5):

[The `pow` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) is probably what you are looking for.

`return pow(10, $n-1);` should be close to what you want but might need tweeking for borderline cases.